# How to locate deleted data from recycle bin in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-8.1, recycle-bin, forensics

I'm using Windows 7, but I tested Windows 8.1 with the same results. From what I understand deleted files in recycle bin are stored as $R or $I format, however nothing is visible when I search command prompt as administrator.

```
C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\%SID%>dir /a
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is _

 Directory of C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\%SID%

02/23/2015  02:28 PM    <DIR>          .
02/23/2015  02:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/23/2015  01:27 PM               129 desktop.ini
           1 File(s)            129 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  124,504,084,480 bytes free
```

Comment: I can see my deleted files just fine using `dir`, are you sure you have the correct SID, drive and actually deleted files?

Comment: The SID is correct, I tried the administrator SID too. I can see files in $R and $I format when they are simply in the recycle bin. But for files after I empty the recycle bin nothing can be viewed in cmd.

Comment: Oh I missed that 'deleted data from recycle bin'. After you emptied your recycle bin, Windows doesn't know about these files anymore, you need to use third party tools to list them. What's $R or $I format anyways?

Comment: Like $RN6LOVC.txt or $IN6LOVC.txt. Don't know any more than that. Maybe I'm wrong about files remaining that format when they are fully deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emptying the Recycle Bin will delete those files. If you want to recover the files try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). You can experiment with this behavior as follows:

1. Create a directory and a `test.txt` file inside it with contents
2. Delete the directory
3. Locate the directory in both the Recycle Bin Explorer window with the command line
4. Verify the contents of the `test.txt` with:

`type C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\%SID%\$R......\test.txt`

5. In the Recycle Bin Explorer window delete the directory
6. Observe the `$R......` directory and contents are also deleted